# Why does batch file (.bat) converted to executable (.exe) not work?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, converters

So I have a batch file that I am trying to convert but i'm no success. The converter that I am using is
[Bat To Exe Converter](http://www.f2ko.de/programs.php?lang=en&pid=b2e). The problem that I am encountering is that after converting the batch file it does not execute properly and immediately says "Press any key to continue . . ." and then closes. The batch file works fine on its own and when I converted it using the websites online converter it also worked (I would use the online but has little functions and is not exactly what I need).

Below is the batch code that I am using:

```
@ECHO OFF
TITLE ADB Over Network Running...
COLOR 17
CLS
IF "%ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS%" == "" GOTO NOPATH
ADB tcpip 5555
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO END
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 GOTO NEXT
GOTO END
:NEXT
set /P ip=Enter Devices IP: %=%
ADB connect %ip%
GOTO END
:NOPATH
ECHO "ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS" not found. Please add this environment variable
GOTO END
:END
PAUSE
EXIT
```

I hope that you can help me. Thank you for any help and your time :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As all that program does is extract the batch file into a subfolder of temp and execute it, Windows has the exact same feature.

Type

```
iexpress
```

in Start - Run and follow the wizard and set your bat to run as the last step.

Comment: vbs or js to exe bit more work but see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adcae113-4758-481a-a367-60d5d14d97d6/this-is-how-to-turn-vbs-and-js-files-into-exe-files-from-the-command-line-without-third-party-tools?forum=scripting